# Sending Push Notifications from Xamarin Application using Azure Notification hubs

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I was able to send push notification from a traditional console application using Azure Notification Hubs Nuget and it works fine but here's the thing I want to be able to send the push Notification from a xamarin Application and it doesn't allow the Nuget to be installed in the PCL project. So is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: If you are able to send push notifications from your Android or iOS project, then you can use the [Xamarin Forms Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/text-to-speech/) from within your PCL project to call the "send push notification" methods in the native projects. Another option would be to have the device call your own server which would do the sending on behalf of the device.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for, how to send it from the android project.  It's a pretty basic application so no server side hosting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the Xamarin.Android SDK has built in methods to send notifications, you would need to check into that yourself.

But if you look at [Azure's Guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started#sending-push-notifications) they show an example of an Android app that sends notifications from the app itself.

That example is using Java but it is simply hitting the Azure Notification Hub's REST interface which is exactly what the SDKs are doing behind the scenes.

That means you can do the same thing from your Xamarin.Android or Xamarin PCL project as well. More info on Azure's Notification Hub REST interface can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn223264.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).